# Changing a Pot's Adjustment Range

Tags: resistors, voltage-regulator, potentiometer

I want to put 24 VDC through a 10 k pot but limit the output on the wiper to 2.5 V. Could you advise me what value and where to put the resistors please? There is no load on the circuit as it's just a 0-2.5 V input signal to a temp controller.

Answer (score 1):

By using resistors in series with the pot, the minimum and maximum voltages can be biased to a certain voltage range. In this case, the pot needs to go to 0V, so the one end of the pot can be connected to GND. the upper end of the pot should stop at 2.5V, so we need a resistor to add a voltage drop of 21.5V between the 24V supply and the 2.5V max. Like so:

[image: circuit]

Since we know that we want 2.5V out when the pot resistance is max at 10K, using ohm's law, the current is 250uA.

```
2.5V/10K = 250uA
```

The top resistor also must have 250uA flowing through it too, and it we need a voltage drop of 21.5V, so also using ohm's law, it is 86K.

```
21.5V/250uA = 86K
```

The nearest resistor value is a 1% 86.6K Working backwards from that, the voltage range is going to be 0 - 2.48V

However: 
This will only work if the load resistance is high. If the load resistance is comparable to the 10K resistance of the pot, then the combined resistance of the load and the pot will change the voltage divider ratio and increase the amount of current flow, increasing the voltage.

Comment: thanks for the reply, your answer was looking good until the "however" bit. as my 0-2.5v is only a input reference to a heater controller then i guess there is no load resistance as such.. is this correct? is there any way of doing what i want?

Comment: .is it possible to just add a large resistor across the output? would this work? how big would it need to be?